# Universal coefficient theorem maps

Tags: group-theory, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a group and $A$ a trivial $G$-module. The Universal Coefficient Theorem yields a split exact sequence

$$0\longrightarrow {\rm Ext}(H_{n-1}(G),A)\longrightarrow H^n(G,A)\longrightarrow {\rm Hom}(H_n(G),A)\longrightarrow 0.$$

In terms of cohomology classes, what is the explicit description of the map ${\rm Ext}(H_{n-1}(G),A)\to H^n(G,A)$?

In the case $n=2$, the map is induced by the epimorphism $G\to G^{\rm ab}$.

Additional questions: How does the splitting map ${\rm Hom}(H_n(G),A)\to H^n(G,A)$ act, again explicitly in terms of homomorphisms $H_n(G)\to A$ and elements of $H^n(G,A)$? Or maybe, if it's easier, what is the splitting map $H^n(G,A)\to {\rm Ext}(H_{n-1}(G),A)$?

Edit: As the first comment below shows, splitting maps may not have nice explicit descriptions.

Comment: This should be apparent from the proof (see for example Weibels book on hom alg Th. 3.6.5).  One should keep in mind that the sequence splits, but not naturally. It just splits as a short exact sequence of abelian groups. A nice cocycle description of the splitting map can therefore not be expected.

Comment: I am familiar with different proofs of UCT, but I'm having troubles with explicit description. If I think of ${\rm Ext}(H_{n-1}(G),A)$ as the the set of cohomology classes $[f]$ represented by symmetric 2-cocycles $f:H_{n-1}(G)\times H_{n-1}(G)\to A$, what is the image of $[f]$ in $H^n(G,A)$?